# Can Doctrine be used with a Postgres DB & MSSQL DB at the same time?

Tags: php, sql-server, api, postgresql, doctrine

At my work we have two separate sites that are very closely related.  One of them is a ASP/MSSQL site and the other is a PHP/Postgres site.

I want to create a REST API that everything from now on is built on top of.  I would like it to be tied to both DBs so that it can be a a single point of retrieving and setting data.

I was thinking of using a DBA like Doctine to keep from writing queries in two different syntax.  In the same system is it possible to tie parts of Doctrine to the MSSQL and other parts to Postgres?

If so, how? Any other thoughts on design are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Within your application framework, you need to configure two separate entity managers, each of which will connect to a different database. More on entity managers at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

The core architectural pattern is that your models are plain PHP objects, and the entity manager (Data Mapper) will read the mapping configuration to know how to map the models to a database.

Comment: Thank I'll definitely look into this!

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a REST based API it shouldn't really matter what the DB backend is. For example, if you write your API in a combination of Django and tastypie, you could simply swap out a settings.py config to work with both Postgres and MySQL... or even MongoDB if you so chose

The point is, a REST API is a generic solution that can be used by a multitude of languages, you should chose a framework that allows you the same flexibility in DB backends to implement.

Comment: The point of making the API is to have the generic solution, however the question I asked was referring to building the API not using it ;)